# Cannot initialize type 'SelectListItem' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a `SelectListItem` list to use on my view.

I tried using Linq to pass it to ViewBag like this:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.EmailAccounts = db.EmailAccounts.Select(e => new SelectListItem { e.ID, e.Name });
        return View();
    }
```

But it gives me this error:

> Cannot initialize type 'SelectListItem' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

I got the idea to do it this way from here: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

What concept am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing property names in object initializer:

```
new SelectListItem { Value = e.ID, Text = e.Name }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving this error because of a different syntax error (using `=>` instead of `=`).

eg, this:

```
new SelectListItem { Text => e.Name}
```

should be this:

```
new SelectListItem { Text = e.Name}
```